# "Signature of configuration file has changed!" after running ''overcommit --sign"

Tags: rubygems, ruby-overcommit

After installing overcommit and signing the `.overcommit.yml` local file I still get a 'sign' requirement.

```
$ overcommit --sign
Updating signature for configuration file...
$ git commit
Unable to load configuration from '/Users/sergii/w/profinda_saas/.overcommit.yml': Signature of configuration file has changed!
Run `overcommit --sign` once you've verified the configuration changes.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is in different versions of `overcommit` gems. 
Remove versions that are different from the one that was used to create the `.overcommit.yml` file. Install the correct version and re-install hooks.

```
 $ gem uninstall overcommit
 $ gem install overcommit -v 0.46.0 
 $ overcommit --install
 $ overcommit --sign
```